# Problems Wix Installer on Windows Server 2016

Tags: wix, windows-services, windows-server-2016

I've a Wix 3.10 installer with 3 Windows Service, when i run the MSI in my local PC (Windows 8) the Services are installed correctly. I can Stop, Start and too Unistall the Services with the MSI.

The problem is when I install the MSI on Windows Server 2016, I can't Stop and Unistall the service. The Xml of the Wix Installer is the Next.

```
<ServiceInstall
                Id="WindowsService"
                Name="Service"
                DisplayName="My windows Service"
                Description="Process text Files and moves them into Database"
                Type="ownProcess"
                Vital="yes"
                Start="auto"
                Account="[WIX_ACCOUNT_LOCALSERVICE]"
                ErrorControl="critical"
                Interactive="no"/>
            <ServiceControl
                Id="ServiceControl"
                Name="Service"
                Start="install"
                Stop ="both"
                Remove="uninstall"
                Wait="yes"/>
        </Component>
```

Comment: More detail needed: do you get an error message/number when you install? Uninstall? What does it mean when you say "when I install the MSI on Windows Server 2016, I can't Stop and Unistall the service.", because If you are doing an install then why are you trying to stop and uninstall the service?  Are you doing an upgrade?